# Xamarin Forms ShellItemRenderer TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I got an error when trying to update from `Xamarin.Forms` 4.7.x to 5.0.2012.

Here is the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error: ShellItemRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener
public class ShellItemRenderer  MaxGo.Droid C:\Users\root\Downloads\trial3-ori\trial3\MaxGo.Droid\obj\Debug\130\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\ShellItemRenderer.java    4   
Error       error: TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener
public class TabbedPageRenderer MaxGo.Droid C:\Users\root\Downloads\trial3-ori\trial3\MaxGo.Droid\obj\Debug\130\android\src\crc64720bb2db43a66fe9\TabbedPageRenderer.java   4
```

I have following this github issue from this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14492) and have tried to

1. Update Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.5.0.2
2. Update Xamarin Forms to 5.0.0.2125

Any idea?

Comment: I saw a comment in that issue link itself does that not work for you?  `Updating Xamarin.Forms to 5.0.0.2401 and then explicitly updated both Xamarin.Android to 1.7.0.2 and Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.5.0.2 fixed it for me`